# useContext adding unwanted rows/doing unwanted renders when triggered by onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm new to using Contexts and it seems I'm triggering unwanted renders due to my use of Context. It passes the data fine, but I've noticed that my table gets rows added on. If I start out with 50 rows of data, it becomes 100 after I trigger a onclick that is supposed to take me from the Table component to a DetailsPage component. If I click on the another row it adds another 50 and so on....

I used a context to pass the data onto the page that renders its details, as a weird mimic of how it would be in backend (if I had one). Currently, I have this in my App.js where the context is created and passed around:

```
export const vesselContext = createContext();

const App = () => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState();

  return (
    <vesselContext.Provider value={{ rowData, setRowData }}>
      <Routes>
          <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path='/table' element={<Table />} />
          <Route path='/table/details' element={<DetailsPage/>} />
          <Route path='/settings' element={<UserSettings />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </vesselContext.Provider>
  );

}

export default App;
```

I'm loading the context in the table page and setting the new data like so:

```
const { setRowData } = useContext(vesselContext);

function passData(event, row){
 setRowData(row);
 ....
}

<Table>
....
<Button onClick={(event)=>{passData(event, row)} ... />
</Table>
```

I'm guessing setting the row data causes a state change and ends up "rerendering" my table? But my original table doesn't change, I don't see an active refresh either. It just... Adds on rows?? I tried making the onclick a callback instead but it still happened. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line :

```
<vesselContext.Provider value={{ rowData, setRowData }}>
```

Every time your `rowData` changes, the context will create a new value and update every dependencies, including your table.

In other words, even if your table only requires `setRowData` from the provider, because the provider changes when `rowData` changes, and your table is dependent of the value provided, then it is rerendered.

Your provider, in your situation, is not ideal.

A solution would be to manually implement the provider's state. Something like this:

```
const VesselContext = createContext({
   get rowData() { throw new Error('Missing provider'); },
   registerMonitor(handler) { throw new Error('Missing provider'); },
   setRowData(rowData) { throw new Error('Missing provider'); },
});

const vesselContextValue = () => {
   const internal = {
      monitors: new Set(),
      rowData: null,
   };

   return {
      get rowData() { return internal.rowData; },
      registerMonitor(handler) {
         internal.monitors.add(handler);
         return () => internal.monitors.delete(handler);
      },
      setRowData(rowData) {
         internal.rowData = rowData;

         for (const monitor of internal.monitors) {
            monitor(rowData);
         }
      }
   };
}

export const VesselProvider = ({ children }) => (
   <VesselContext.Provider value={ useMemo(() => vesselContextValue(), []) }>
     { children }
   </VesselContext.Provider>      
);

export const useVessel = () => useContext(VesselContext);

export const useVesselData = () => {
   const vesselContext = useVessel();
   const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(() => vesselContext.rowData);

   useEffect(() => vesselContext.registerMonitor(setRowData), [vesselContext]);

   return rowData;
}
```

And use it like this

```
<VesselProvider>
  <Routes>
      <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path='/table' element={<Table />} />
      <Route path='/table/details' element={<DetailsPage/>} />
      <Route path='/settings' element={<UserSettings />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</VesselProvider>
```

In your components that can modify and update the data (will not be updated on data change):

```
const { setRowData } = useVessel();
```

In your components that only need to be notified on data change:

```
const rowData = useVesselData();
```

Comment: makes sense! I suspected that the rowData was forcing a render but couldnt stop it... Quick question: what does the ```registerMonitor(handler)``` do exactly? Maybe it's too early I don't quite understand what it's doing.

Comment: This worked like a charm though! Thank you so much for saving my godforsaken table component  (´꒳`)♡

Comment: The function `registerMonitor(handler)` passes the set state function `setRowData` (i.e. inside `useVesselData`) to the provider. Since `useEffect` can return a cleanup function, then `registerMonitor` returns one to remove the set state function. Essentially, this is a clean way to register and cleanup a state change handler through `useEffect`. If you want to understand more, take a look at the Delegate design pattern; you delegate calling `setRowData` to the provider only (i.e. users of `useVessel`), not users of `useVesselData`.