# not refreshing/re-render page if it's the current location

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I haven't found any answers close to what I'm asking for so I'm wondering if that's even a possible? Just to save on performance, is it possible to not refresh/re-render the page I'm currently on when I click on the same page again in the menu bar?

I have a simple menu bar like so:

```
<Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Login />} />

        <Route element={<WebsiteBars />}>
          <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path='/table' element={<Table/>} />
          <Route path='/settings' element={<UserSettings />} />
          <Route path='/help' element={<HelpPage />} />
        </Route>
</Routes>
```

Where I put all the menu bars, app bars, footers etc. into its own component in `WebsiteBars`. Each menu item is just a list item with a link like `component={Link} to={/settings}`. I noticed that if I'm at tables, and click on tables again in the menu, it "rerenders" the page, adding on more data (that I'm fake generating every time I go to the page).

Is it possible to just not re-render the location I'm already in? Can I tell the router to not route again or "deactive" the link if I'm on the same path it leads to?

Edit: to clarify what exactly I don't want to re-render (if it's even possible), since this seems like expected behaviour. When I click on the Table link in the menu it "rerenders" the page by just adding on more rows, without actually giving me a new table:

The App.js in its full form is like this, whereas the VesselProvider is a provider that I also had to ask a question for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961677/usecontext-adding-unwanted-rows-doing-unwanted-renders-when-triggered-by-onclick):

```
<VesselProvider>
 <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Login />} />

        <Route element={<WebsiteBars />}>
          <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path='/table' element={<Table/>} />
          <Route path='/settings' element={<UserSettings />} />
          <Route path='/help' element={<HelpPage />} />
        </Route>
 </Routes>
</VesselProvider>
```

As for the part I wish it wouldn't re-render when I click on the navigation bar (when I'm already on that page) is basically just the normal MUI Table:

```
const DefaultTable = ({ data }) => {
//some use effects and what not to populate the table with data prop
  const { setRowData } = useVessel(); //from that VesselProvider above
<Table> ... </Table> //nothing special, just the MUI table component with my data
}
```

I'm currently "mocking" the data by using Faker, here is how I'm generating the data:

```
const rows = [];

const randSize = faker.datatype.number({ min: 10, max: 150 });


function fakeData() {
    for (let i = 0; i < randSize; i++) {

        rows.push(
            {
                status: faker.helpers.arrayElement(['sent', 'waiting', 'missing', 'resolved', 'read', 'created', 'modified']),
                ID: faker.random.numeric(6),
                filename: `${randTitle}.${faker.helpers.arrayElement(['xml', 'pptx'])}`,
                filesize: faker.datatype.number({ min: 10, max: 200 }) + "KB",
                subject: faker.helpers.arrayElement(['Invoice', 'Order']),
            }
        )
    }
    return rows;
}

const Table=()=>{
 <DefaultTable data={fakeData()} />
}
```

I wonder if this "weird behaviour" would be avoided if I had an actual backend API to fetch the data from?

Comment: Is it an issue if parts of your React app rerender? From what you describe this seems to behavior I'd expect, but then again, I'm not entirely sure what or how you are determining what was *actually* rerendered. Can you edit your post to include a [mcve] of the relevant code you think you have an issue with or are trying to optimize? Generally clicking a link to navigate to a page you are already on is a non-op in `react-router`, so your code might be doing something "odd".

Comment: I assumed this is the "normal" behaviour since that's how every website seems to work, but I'm wondering if I can "fix" it since the table that is getting triggered doesn't seem to behave right either @DrewReese , if you could take a look again with my edit that'd be great ^^

Comment: If you are faking data, and each time the component renders it creates *new* fake data, then yeah, I'd expect there to be additional rerenders. It might be easier to see what any issue is if you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that we could inspect live.

Comment: I suspected as much... Since I'm calling a function to create the data it seems to just trigger it without actually refreshing the entire table if I just click on the same link again. I'll just leave it as is and swap it out with a proper backend API as my "solution", thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this doesn't answer your question completely. But you can try HOC (High order component).

It can be done something like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <CustomLayout>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/landing" element={<Landing />} />
        <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
        <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={<Navigate to="/landing" replace />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </CustomLayout>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

This `CustomLayout` is the HOC, so every time you change route/path it doesn't re-render completely. It only loads those specific components, `Landing`, `Page2`, `Page3`.

And here is how you can define your HOC:

```
class CustomLayout extends React.Component<ILayoutProps> {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
        <Header style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
          <CustomHeader />
        </Header>
        <Content>
          {children}
        </Content>
        <Footer style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
          <CustomFooter />
        </Footer>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

And try suspense. Here:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html
- https://blog.bitsrc.io/lazy-loading-react-components-with-react-lazy-and-suspense-f05c4cfde10c

Another ref, that may come in handy on HOC:

- https://github.com/maifeeulasad/react-pipeline/blob/main/src/layout/CustomLayout.tsx#L37

Comment: In this implementation `CustomLayout` is what is called a wrapper component. It *wraps* JSX and renders it via the `children`. A Higher Order component is a function taking a React component as an argument and returns a React component.

Comment: @DrewReese sorry about that... feel free to edit the answer... really appreciate it...